# Proof $\frac{a_n^2+a_{n+1}^2+1}{a_{n}a_{n+1}} $ is constant

Tags: induction

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Question:   Defined by $a_{1} =1,a_{2}=2$   and    $a_n a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}^2+1(n\geq 1)$

Proof. $\frac{a_n^2+a_{n+1}^2+1}{a_{n}a_{n+1}} $ is constant for  $n\geq 1$

I tried (Mathematical Induction)  but couldn’t get it that way.

Comment: Your problem reduces to $$\frac{a_n + a_{n + 2}}{a_{n + 1}}$$ using the condition $a_n a_{n + 2} = a^{2}_{n + 1} + 1$

Comment: @Mattos, I got that too, but NikolajK finished it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b_n:=\dfrac{a_n^2+(a_{n+1}^2+1)}{a_{n}a_{n+1}}=\dfrac{a_n^2+(a_{n}a_{n+2})}{a_{n}a_{n+1}}=\dfrac{a_n+a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}$

and

$b_{n+1}=\dfrac{(a_{n+1}^2)+a_{n+2}^2+(1)}{a_{n+1}a_{n+2}}=\dfrac{(a_na_{n+2})+a_{n+2}^2}{a_{n+1}a_{n+2}}=\dfrac{a_n+a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}=b_n$

Answer (score 1):

The formula $$\frac{a_n^2+a^2_{n+1}+1}{a_na_{n+2}}=3$$ holds for $n=1,2$. Assume it is true for $k$ and show it is true for $k+1$. Here is another approach:

$$
\frac{a_{k+1}^2+a^2_{k+2}+1}{a_{k+1}a_{k+2}}\cdot\frac{a_{k}}{a_{k}}
=\frac{a_{k+1}^2+a^2_{k+2}+1}{a_{k}a_{k+2}}\cdot\frac{a_{k}}{a_{k+1}}
=\frac{a_{k+1}^2+a^2_{k+2}+1}{a_{k+1}^2+1}\cdot\frac{a_{k}}{a_{k+1}}
$$
$$
=\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}\left(\frac{a_{k+1}^2+1}{a_{k+1}^2+1}+\frac{a_{k+2}^2}{a_{k+1}^2+1}\right)
=\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}\left(1+\frac{a_{k+2}^2}{a_k a_{k+2}}\right)
=\frac{a_k+a_{k+2}}{a_{k+1}}.
$$

So now we need to show that is constant in $k$. See solution above by NikolajK.